# Linux kernel on_each_cpu run on only one cpu (cpu0)

Tags: linux-kernel

I have this:

```
static void per_cpu_print(void *info)
{
        printk("cccpuID = %d\n", smp_processor_id());
}

static void test(void)
{
        on_each_cpu(per_cpu_print, NULL, 1);
}
```

`test` runs before `rest_init` in the kernel boot sequence.

I only see one print: cccpuID = 0

Im running ubuntu 16 with the 4.15 kernel inside VMware Workstation and I gave it 4 cores, haven changed anything in the kernel regarding smp.

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons. You run on single processor system, you havent configured smp, you have set NCPU to 1 in kernel config...

Comment: Im not that dumb xD, im running in a VM with 4 cores. I havent changed anything regarding smp so it should be whatever the linux kernel does by default.

Comment: what have you you tried to solve this issue?

Comment: Nothing really.... I just assumed im using `on_each_cpu` before something that it needs was initialized since linux supports smp by default so I shouldnt need to do anything for it to work... (Unless im wrong somewhere)